# Angular ChangeDetection NgIf

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

So i am trying to better understand Angulars ChangeDetection and stumbled into a problem:
https://plnkr.co/edit/M8d6FhmDhGWIvSWNVpPm?p=preview

This Plunkr is a simplified version of my applications code and basically has a **parent** and a **child** component. 
Both having `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` enabled.

parent.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: `
            <button (click)="click()">Load data</button>
            {{stats.dataSize > 0}}
            <span *ngIf="stats.dataSize > 0">Works</span>
            <child [data]="data" [stats]="stats" (stats)="handleStatsChange()"></child>
        `,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnCheck, OnChanges {

    data = [];
    stats = {
        dataSize: 0
    };

   constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
   }

    click() {
        console.log("parent: loading data");
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.data = ["Data1", "Data2"];
            this.cdr.markForCheck();
        });
    }

    handleStatsChange() {
        console.log('parent: stats change');
        this.cdr.markForCheck();
    }
}
```

child.component.ts

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output, SimpleChanges } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template: `
        <div *ngFor="let item of data">{{item}}</div>
    `,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

    @Input() data;
    @Input() stats;
    @Output('stats') statsEmitter = new EventEmitter();

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }


    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        console.log("child changes: ", changes);

        this.stats.dataSize = changes['data'].currentValue.length;
        this.statsEmitter.emit(this.stats);
    }
}
```

So parent updates `data` on button click which triggers `ngOnChanges` in child.
Everytime data changes, `child.component` changes a value in `stats`. 
I want this value, `dataSize`, to be used in the `<span *ngIf="stats.dataSize > 0">Works</span>` in parent. 
For some reason the `*ngIf` wont be updated. The template `{{stats.dataSize > 0}}` otherwise updates no problem.

What i noticed:
If i remove `OnPush` on parent, Angular will throw a exception `Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.`.
I guess this comes from `*ngIf="stats.dataSize > 0"` being false first and now true after the second iteration of change detection in dev mode.

So thats why i tried setting `this.cdr.markForCheck();` in parent in `handleStatsChange`. `handleStatsChange` will be called in child. This has no consequences thought, exception thrown anyway.

I guess change detection on parent doesnt get triggered because no @Input changed in parent, therefore ngIf doesnt update?? Clicking the button **two** times will actually show `Works`. I this because a new digest cycle does now start (triggered by a Event) and parents ChangeDetectorRef is now updating the template?

**So why does Angular update `{{stats.dataSize > 0}}` and throw an error at ngIf?**

Any help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging a little more into [Lifecycle Hooks Documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) i noticed they provide really nice examples about handling change detection.

In their counter example in `CounterParentComponent` they have to update their `LoggerService` by running a new 'tick', which means delaying execution with `setTimeout`.

counter:

```
updateCounter() {
    this.value += 1;
    this.logger.tick();
}
```

logger:

```
tick() {  this.tick_then(() => { }); }
tick_then(fn: () => any) { setTimeout(fn, 0); }
```

Thats exactlly what i had to do to get my code working. They also mention this in their docs:

> Angular's unidirectional data flow rule forbids updates to the view after it has been composed. Both of these hooks fire after the component's view has been composed.
>   Angular throws an error if the hook updates the component's data-bound comment property immediately (try it!).
>   The LoggerService.tick_then() postpones the log update for one turn of the browser's JavaScript cycle and that's just long enough.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/tAZvxaXKaJKqoproQW7U?p=preview setTimeout will run change detection cycle from root component. You just need to update current view

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue today with intersection observer where scrolling an item into view was supposed to do something and 99% of the time it did but 1% of the time it didn't fire.

Important: The async pipe actually calls `markForCheck` internally. You can look at [the source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts) (near the end).

One solution I've used to this in the past with observables is creating a pipe that creates a 'delay'. This has helped in 'expression changed' errors because it effectively causes a new change detector cycle.

This should be a last resort - but I've used it in a few times when I just couldn't get the timing right elsewhere.

```
<div *ngIf="model.showPanel | delayTime | async">...</div>
```

This will have a default of 0ms and the `delay()` RxJS pipe uses setTimeout:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'delayTime'
})
export class DelayTimePipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor() {}

    transform(value?: Observable<any> | any, ms?: number): Observable<any> {
        if (isObservable(value)) {
            return value.pipe(delay(ms || 0));
        } else {
            throw debuggerError('[DelayTimePipe] Needs to be an observable');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You Sir just saved my day. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In Angular, you can't change a value during the change detection cycle. So,

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        console.log("child changes: ", changes);

        this.stats.dataSize = changes['data'].currentValue.length;  <-- this is not allowed
        this.statsEmitter.emit(this.stats);
    }
```

That's why you're getting the error about a value being changed after it was checked.

Comment: so you mean i should update them in `ngAfterContentChecked`?

Comment: No, that will still cause the error.  Why don't you update the stats when you update the data? i don't see why you are waiting for a life cycle hook in your case